# Can't access props within onToken function

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Folks I'm using react-stripe-checkout to collect my user's credit card info. After collecting the user's details and sending them to my backend I'm trying to call a function from this.props to update state client side but 'this' doesn't have available props/state. Checkout the image to see the scope of 'this' within the onToken function. Is there a way of accessing either props or class functions (e.g. onTokenThen) within onToken?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Axios from 'axios';

export default class AddCustomer extends Component {
  constructor (props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.onTokenThen = this.onTokenThen.bind(this);
  };

  onToken(token) {
    console.log('token', token);
    debugger; // <-- 'this' 
    Axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/api/v1/addCustomer',
      data: {
        stripeToken: token
      }
    })
    .then(this.props.addCustomerState) // <-- can't access props here
    .catch(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

  onTokenThen(customer){
    debugger;
  }

  render() {
    let currentUser = this.props.activeUser.email;
    return (
        <StripeCheckout
          ...
          token={this.onToken}
          ...
          <Button bsStyle="success">
            Add customer
          </Button>
        </StripeCheckout>
    );
  }
};
```

[image: onToken scope]

Comment: `.then(response => this.props.addCustomerState(response))`

Comment: also in your render function `token={() => this.onToken()}`

Comment: I gave your suggestion a go and while it makes available props/state from this, the token itself is lost. But your idea prompted me to try binding the onToken method to this which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding the onToken function to 'this' in the constructor solved the problem; both the token and props/class functions are now available.

```
  constructor (props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.onToken = this.onToken.bind(this); // <-- makes available 'this' in onToken scope
  };
```